# linphonec hangs/freezes on Remote ringing

Tags: linux, sip, linphone

i have issue with **linphonec** on **amazon ec2 instance** with ubuntu.
(on my local ubuntu everything works as expected.)

linphonec hangs when i try to make a call. but chat works w/o problems.

when i start it i get error that pc doesn't have sound card.

`ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'`

it's ok because it's server linux and i don't plan to use it. 
i'm going to record call to file.

so after start i use commands

```
soundcard use files
play welcome.wav
record record.wav
```

when i type `call sip:alice@ip:5080` i see incomming call on another pc but **linphonec is freezed** on the first machine.

when i drop call on the second pc linphonec  is still freezed and i need to use `kill` to terminate process

Answer (score 0):

amazon ec2 instance use ubuntu with the following kernel - `linux-image-virtual kernel​`

this kernel doesn't have `snd-dummy` kernel module

but this module presents in `linux-image-extra-virtual` package.

so we need to install it before execute `modprobe snd-dummy`

After that linphone works w/o problem